# CMD.exe get first day of the month

Tags: date, cmd

Using cmd batch file can i get first day of month and run an action?
For example every first day of the month shutdown the pc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not straightforward in cmd.exe. Trivial in PowerShell. `if ( (get-date).Day -eq 1 ) { ...`

Comment: It's simple in cmd, all you need to do is tell us what date-format you are using (or are you willing to use `wmic` functions to determine the date?)

Comment: for german date format: `echo 01%date:~2%`. For american format: `echo %date:~0,3%01%date:~5%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for german date format: `echo 01%date:~2%`. For american format: `echo %date:~0,3%01%date:~5%`

or use a language independent solution:

```
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('wmic path Win32_LocalTime get month^,year /value^|find "="') doset /a %%i
set DatTim=01.%month%.%year%
REM adapt to your needed format
```

or in your special case:

```
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('wmic path Win32_LocalTime get day /value^|find "="') do set /a %%i
if %day%==1 (
   rem your commands
)
```